# Linear Layout Manager with Recycler view not reversing

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, linearlayoutmanager

I would like to have a recycler view with reversed items and layout, for a chat app. Theoretically this should reverse the layout and stacking order, but the problem is that only one works at a time. If I use reverse layout, it correctly pints to the bottom, but then does not reverse the stacking order. So essentially only one of the desired behaviors work at a time, but not both together.

```
mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
mLinearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
mLinearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
```

Comment: do you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I solved it with just reversing layout manager:

```
        layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
```